# Why am I unable to call .get on json data / how do I convert the json to a map

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to write a test for a function which takes a map as a parameter,

When the code runs normally outside of a test the parameter can take the form (when I call toString):

`Map { "id": "jobs", "label": "Jobs", "nodeType": "ROOT", "childNodesURI": "jobs?owner=*", "childIds": List [], "isFetchingChildren": false, "isToggled": true, "jobName": "" }`

```
var node = {
                id: "jobs", 
                label: "JES Jobs", 
                nodeType: "ROOT", 
                childNodesURI: "jobs?owner=*", 
                childIds: [],
                isFetchingChildren: false, 
                isToggled: true, 
                jobName: "" };
                console.log(node.get("id"));
```

When node.get("id") is called I get "TypeError: node.get is not a function"

I'm assuming this is because there's no function .get() foo a JSON object but not truly sure... If this is the case, how do I convert or initialise the JSON as a map?

Comment: using the Map constructor? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map P.S. You're right, `node` is not a Map, it's a standard JS object.

Comment: @ADyson is there a way I can create the map with just the JSON data rather than having to do map.set(key, value) for each map entry?

Comment: I don't know. All I've looked at is that documentation I linked to. I'd never heard of the Map object before I read this question, I just know how to use Google to find out basic info :-) The constructor takes an `[iteratable]` according to that page, which it defines as "an Array or other iterable object" so try feeding it your `node` object and see if it works. If not try re-creating your object as an array, as per the example in the "Relation with Array objects" section of the page.

Comment: @JordyBobs No need to create a `Map` here. JS objects _are_ maps/dictionaries; you access values at keys using `obj.someKey` or `obj["someKey"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing us is a javascript object. If you need to call a "key" in this case you should use `theObject.theProperty` like below

```js
var node = {
  id: "jobs",
  label: "JES Jobs",
  nodeType: "ROOT",
  childNodesURI: "jobs?owner=*",
  childIds: [],
  isFetchingChildren: false,
  isToggled: true,
  jobName: ""
};

//Call the object property ID
console.log(node.id);
```

If you need a map you need to it this way :

```js
var myMap = new Map();

// setting the values
myMap.set("id", "jobs");

console.log(myMap.get("id"));
```

If you want to create your map starting from your object you can do it like this

```js
var node = {
  id: "jobs",
  label: "JES Jobs",
  nodeType: "ROOT",
  childNodesURI: "jobs?owner=*",
  childIds: [],
  isFetchingChildren: false,
  isToggled: true,
  jobName: ""
};

function buildMap(obj) {
    let map = new Map();
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        map.set(key, obj[key]);
    });
    return map;
}

const map = buildMap(node);

console.log(map.get("id"));
```

Comment: I had to create a Map and then use map.set to prevent having to change production code, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just access `node.id` using the code you have. There is no `get()` method on an object literal unless you extend the prototype yourself.

`Map` should accept an iterable object as a parameter when you create one according to the docs. However in practice I find this generates an `undefined is not a function` error when using an object instead of an array.
Also looking at the docs, the browser support is not complete (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

For example (quoted from above link):

> [1] Starting with Chrome 31, the feature was available behind a preference. In chrome://flags, activate the entry “Enable Experimental JavaScript”.

Your options as I see them are; you can iterate over your JSON

```
var m = new Map();
var json = {'foo': 'bar'};

for(var i in json) {
    m.set(i, json[i]);
}
m.get('foo');
```

Or if you don't really need the `Map` methods stick with the object literal.

```
json.foo;
```